# C# Backgroundworker New Issue

Tags: c#, backgroundworker

I am looking for an efficient solution for my problems. I am using VS 2010. I want to do a series of operations from wcf service method and send back the each operations status to the calling client. I have setup wcf with callback contract and using duplex channel, I am able to connect to wcf. When I start the long running operation, sometimes, it will trigger the call back sometimes it is not. I dont know why. Below is the method I was following.

In the wcf service method,

```
 public void Start()
  {
      List<Employee> empLists = GetEmpData();  // geting lots of employee objects
      foreach(Employee emp in empLists)        // maybe 1000 records
      {
          StartlongRunning(emp);
      }
  }

 private void StartlongRunning(Employee emp)
 {
     // here i am creating a new background worker...
     // Here i am registering for RunWorkerCompleted, DoWork, ReportProgress events...
     bgw.RunWorkerAsync(emp)
 }

 void bgw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
 {
     Employee emp = (Employee)e.Argument;
     using (ClassA p = new ClassA(emp.ID)) // this class is from another dll.
     {
       e.Result = p.StartProcess(emp.Code);
     } 
 }

 void bgw_RunWorkerCompleted(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
 {
    // This is not calling properly.
    // Sometimes this method is working...most of the time it is not working..
    // here i am unregistering the registerd DoWork, RunWorkerCompleted events...
    // calling bgw.Dispose(); // i tried without this also;...but no use...
    // from here I am firing the callback to client...
 }
```

Here is the implementation of the StartProcess method.

```
 public string StartProcess(string empcode)
 {
     // call to another method1() // here saving to DB frequently. works fine
     // call to another method2() // here also saving to DB frequently. works fine
     // call to someother method3()  // here also some DB insert frequently. fine
     // call to Method4() // here also some DB insert.
                          // this method is not calling frequently..
                          // sometimes it is calling but most of times not..why ???
     return value;
 }

 private void SaveToDB(args1, args2...)
 {
     DatabaseHelper.Save(args1, args2.....); // this static class is from another dll
     // only DB operation in this static class..
 }
```

The implemenation of this static class is as shown below.

```
using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(DBConnection))
{
     conn.open;
      using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
      {
         ...adding parameters
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      conn.close();
}
```

If the `StartProcess` returns, then the background worker will execute the `RunWorker` method.
But it is not happening. What is wrong in here?

I am creating each `ClassA` object for each background worker.
And once an object of `ClassA` is completed, then it will be disposed.

But i don't know why the `StartProcess` is not returning the call properly.

In my implementation, is there overlapping of `ClassA` objects between background workers ??

Comment: I am not sure if this is your problem but it looks like you may be trying to open over 1000 SqlConnections concurrently. How many connections you can get at one time is a database server configuration issue. If your DB only supplies three connections, you will end up with almost all of your background threads in a waiting state until the operations on those three connections are used.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens. Thanks for the reply. But it is working properly sometimes. When i run the application, i checked the DB by executing the count from each table. In each frequent click on run buton in the sql query window, the count is increasing for the tables of the method 1, 2 and 3. But the table for the Method 4 is not updating. It is showing count 0. But 1 or 2 times when i run tha app, all the 4 tables are showing count, which means everything is working properly. I dont undestand what is the problem here ??

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you call RunWorkerAsync in a loop without checking that it is not busy.
You should call RunWorkerAsync with the list as the parameter rather than trying to start all the work in different threads.

I would do something like this:

```
 public void Start()
 {
     List<Employee> empLists = GetEmpData();  // geting lots of employee objects
     StartlongRunning(empLists);
 }
```

And change bgw_DoWork accordingly.

If you need to see the progress you could call ReportProgress for each employee object.

Comment: I think this is a good idea and let me check it. But sequential executing will affect the performance ???

Comment: Yes it is working fine. But executing each item is very time consuming. I was looking for something doing it in parallel.

Comment: I thought that you were updating a database, making it parallel will not make it much faster because the database will make it sequential anyway because it locks tables and indexes while updating.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create application to work with several backgroundWorkers in the same time you should initialize new backgroundWorker object for each operations you are doing.. That will solve the problem.

Comment: Vasic. Thanks for the reply. But i am creating new bgw for each operation. Can you specify more abt your idea ?

Comment: As i see . You are runing same backgroundWorker . You can create BackgroundWorker bw = new BackgroundWorker(); instance or array with every call . and you can add event for each one something like this from code not from designer.
worker.DoWork += new DoWorkEventHandler(update.DoUpdate);